# Transforming an image to black and white (not grayscale)

Tags: c#, image-processing, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

is there a way to thresholding an image in Xamarin.Forms or Xamarin.Android?

I'd like to thresholding every photo taken with the camera in android (one at a time), currently i am using xlabs for the camera capture.

I have searched but I have not found anything helpful. Maybe you guys can help me. :)

Comment: @willaien thank you for the info., but ideally I want an image that is just monchrome black and white only, not greyscale. This makes the text clearer and easier to use OCR on.

Comment: you can do it. I will show you how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So to do this,you can use [OpenCV Library for Android](http://opencv.org/).

1. Download [from here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-android/3.0.0/OpenCV-3.0.0-android-sdk-1.zip/download)(for e.g.) **version 3.0.0**
2. Now you need to add [***Android Java Binding Library***](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/java_integration_overview/binding-a-java-library/) into your Xamarin.Android project(also you can read this [great article](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/java_integration_overview/binding-a-java-library/binding-a-jar/))
3. When ***Android Java Binding Library*** was added to your project,you need to add .jar,that was generated from **OpenCV SDK** via [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html)(but i've made this for you, here is [link](https://www.sendspace.com/file/r5hjs9) of generated .jar).
4. In your ***Android Java Binding Library*** -> Folder(**Jars**) add existing file(.jar that is from step 3),also you need to add **shared objects** to the Jar folder(from YourPathWhereIsStoreSDK/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/libs/armeabi...etc).
   Result must be similar to this:
   [image: result of items]
5. Now in your Xamarin.Android project you must put reference to ***Android Java Binding Library*** project.
6. See code below,how you can use this Library :).

In your splash activity(Or MainActivity) add this:

```
   //beware,that we need to INIT Only once,so better to put in SplashActivity
    public  MainActivity()
            {
                if (!OpenCVLoader.InitDebug())
                {
                    System.Console.WriteLine("Failed to INIT \n OpenCV Failure");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.Console.WriteLine("OpenCV INIT Succes");
                }

            }
```

Now we can convert image to b/w:

```
void ConvertImageToBW()
    {
        Mat MatToBW = new Mat();
        using (Bitmap SourceImg = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(BitmapFactory.DecodeFile(App._file.Path)))  //App._file.Path  - path of image that we have made by camera 
        {
            if (SourceImg != null)
            {
                Utils.BitmapToMat(SourceImg,MatToBW);
                //first we convert to grayscale
                Imgproc.CvtColor(MatToBW, MatToBW, Imgproc.ColorRgb2gray);
                //now converting to b/w
                Imgproc.Threshold(MatToBW, MatToBW, 0.5 * 255, 255, Imgproc.ThreshBinary);
                using(Bitmap newBitmap = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(MatToBW.Cols(),MatToBW.Rows(),Bitmap.Config.Argb8888))
                {
                    Utils.MatToBitmap(MatToBW, newBitmap);
                    //put result in your imageView, B/W Image
                    imageView.SetImageBitmap(newBitmap);
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Now just use this method into your OnActivityResult.
Enjoy!

Comment: This works like a charm, thank you so much. I had one issue though, OpenCV did not want to initialize, I change the target framework to Android 4.4 (Kit Kat) in the Android Java Binding Library options and it worked. :D